# Convert date from string to timestamp in impala

Tags: hive, impala

I know this question has already been asked but my input is different. Also I have not found any documentation on this.

I have to convert a **string** to **timestamp** in Impala, and I am doing like-

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('Mon Jan 02 06:30:40 EST 2006', 'EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zzz yyyy')) as timestamp
```

This is showing me error.

The query is working on HIVE but I want to do it in IMPALA.

I want the output as -

```
2006-01-02 06:30:40
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this?

Comment: `06:60:40` ? ....

Comment: Its `06:30:40`. I changed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the final string format of how you want the end-date presented.

Tested this on Impala 2.7 and seems to be working.

```
SELECT from_unixtime((unix_timestamp('Mon Jan 02 06:30:40 GMT 2006', 'EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zzz yyyy')), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') AS result
```

NB: I've switched to GMT in the above example.

Using documentation from:

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html#datetime_functions__from_unixtime

Comment: I am using v2.5.0     
Its not working in this version.

It is giving this error- 
`Error during Execute
 S1000(110)[Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (110) Error while executing a query in Impala: [HY000] : Runtime Error: Query a4678a38a5da3b3:6016bf88adb6d79b 100% Complete (0 out of 0)
Bad date/time conversion format: EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zzz yyyy`